# Retrieval of data from database using mysql

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I need to make a project of making a Professor timetable retrieval system.I plan to create a a html page and make a drop-down menu use some CSS scripting and php; selecting the professor's name and day of the week. This directs to the database where the selected professor's table is stored and then it must show in result that day professor's schedule.

I'm making a 6 tables that would like Monday,Tuesday...Saturday each table having attributes p_id,p_name,period 1,period 2,...,period 8.

My exact question is how to retrieve the specific professor's data on a particular day?

Comment: html + css won't get you there, they are front-end languages, html is for document markup and css is to style that markup. Neither are capable of accessing a database (to my knowledge using straight-up html and css) - you need to look into a back-end language like PHP (my personal favourite) or (my most hated nightmare) .net - but PHP is better ;) with php - you'll be able to talk to your server :)

Comment: Opps! I forgot to specify php , php will be used to make server connectivity with mysql

Comment: haha no worries :) in that case, you'll need to take a look into either `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` - I have used more `mysqli_` but I'm unsure as to what is better.

Comment: how to retrieve the specific professor's data on a particular day......well...simple....write mysql query and tell us what dataset do you get...

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you will be using PHP. Have you set up your database tables yet?

As a rough guess, you will need at least a `professor` table and a `professor_appointment` table. The `professor` table could have an auto-incrementing `id`, personal name fields and whatever else you deem relevant.

The `professor_appointment` will have a `professor_id` field, which is a foreign key link to the `professor` table. It will also need `start_time` and `end_time` fields, maybe `title`, `description` etc.

To retrieve the specific professor's data on a particular day, you would need a query like:

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM professor_appointment pa
    INNER JOIN professor p ON pa.professor_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
    AND DATE( pa.start_time ) = '2017-07-20'
ORDER BY pa.start_time ASC;
```

This would retrieve all of the appointments on 20th July 2017 for the professor with id 1 in the `professor` table.

A couple of things possible worth explaining in this SQL query:

- Aliases are used for the tables, so the `p` after the `professor` table is its alias and every reference thereafter to the `professor` table just uses the alias `p`.
- `DATE( pa.start_time )` The DATE function is just wrapped around the `start_time` field to effectively remove the time elements of the field (hours, minutes etc) to just leave the date itself for simple comparison.

Comment: Is there any way the I can retrieve the timetable on a specific day of the week like it gives timetable of Monday?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want here, is it the timetable for:
 - Monday of the current week?
 - Monday of the next week?
 - The next Monday after today?
 - The Monday in the same week as a given date?

I would want to write this date code in the PHP code, rather than in SQL, but it could be done in SQL.

Comment: If I want to see today's timetable i.e. Friday then I have to select Friday from drop-down menu and it retrieves Friday's timetable. So its like current day schedule.

Comment: For the current day's schedule, just change the line `AND DATE( pa.start_time ) = '2017-07-20'` to `AND DATE( pa.start_time ) = CURDATE()`.